# How to use Rotating Progress Bar?

Tags: java, android

Hi i'm using Rotating Progress Bar in my Android Music Plyer Application....I'm not able to stop it. While working with horizontal Progress bar i used handler to stop and start it.
  But while working with Rotating One, The progress bar goes into Infinite Loop.....

Can you please suggest method to stop the indefinite loop. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using ProgressBar#dismiss() method?

**EDIT:** `dismiss()` is only for `ProgressDialog`. For `ProgressBar` you should toggle the Visibilty of the View.

If `mHandler` is a Handler bound to your UI thread and `mProgress` is your `ProgressBar`, you can have something like the following from inside the run method of your background thread:

```
 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for super fast reply.Can you provide the handler code snippet where the dismiss method needs to be written.

Comment: Rahul is correct(+10 to him for pointing out this subtlety). A ProgressDialog is dismissed. A ProgressBar is just a view that can be made Visible/invisible/Gone.
If mHandler is a Handler bound to UI thread you can say something like:
 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                         public void run() {
                             mProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         }
                     });

Answer (score 3):

You can dismiss a ProgressDialog. **A progressBar is just a view you can make set its visibility as visible or invisible** based on your requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable d = yourActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
d.setBounds(progressbar.getIndeterminateDrawable().getBounds());
progressbar.setIndeterminateDrawable(d);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and if you can please add some notes and explain your solution.